# After and before for scrollable ol

Tags: html, css

I have borders on my ol that I want to animate the position of, but they scroll with the content. Is there a way to make them fixed without introducing another node?

```css
div{
  height: 100vh;
  width: 30%;
}
ol{
  height: 60%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  position: relative;
}
ol::before,
ol::after{
  content: '';
  height: 5px;
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
ol::after{
  bottom: 0;
}
li{
  height: 300%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ol>
    <li/>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't tell what you're asking. Maybe add some `<li>`s so we can see some content? Also reduce the heights and/or widths so things take up a small amount of space.

Comment: I might know what you mean... what if you do borders on the top and bottom of the `ol` itself? I don't know if that would work with the animation. Ii might mean animating the whole list, not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solution: **Move Relative Position to Preceding Ancestor**

The position of an element with `position: absolute` is ultimately relative to the closest ancestor with a position other than static. If we have the `ol` position undefined, and instead set its parent (the div) to `position: relative` it takes the absolute positioning out of the scrolling behavior of the ol... Then, the top and/or bottom values of the pseudo elements depend on the the div/parent rather than the ol itself, so adjust the bottom value accordingly. In this case, it would be bottom: 40% to offset the height of the ol you defined as 60%.

```css
div {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 30%;
  position: relative;
}

ol {
  height: 60%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

ol::before,
ol::after {
  content: '';
  height: 5px;
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

ol::after {
  bottom: 40%;
}

li {
  height: 300%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ol>
    <li/>
  </ol>
</div>
```

I'm not quite sure if this is what you are looking for, and I will edit my answer to clarify anything, as needed. I will also try to update with some references asap.